# Include CMake project dependency include directories with -isystem

Tags: gcc, cmake, googletest, gcc-warning

A project I'm working on links to Google test (gtest) as a dependency. The google test headers are included in the project though CMake's interface dependencies, using the CMakeLists included in the google test project.

`target_link_libraries (our_project gtest gmock)`

Some of the warning flags that we have used for our project are printing tons of warnings in google test- for instance, GCC's `-Wsuggest-override`. Ideally these warnings would not be printed since they originate in a library, and I think including the library headers with `-isystem` is the correct way to do this. However, I'm not sure how to configure CMake to use `-isystem` for a specified library.

Is there a way we can specify a library dependency as a system library without modifying gtest, and ignore the warnings from it?

Answer (score 1):

`target_include_directories()` provides a `SYSTEM` option which does what you want.  Or, if the target is an imported library target, populate the `INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property as opposed to the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property.

Comment: I'm aware of this flag, but the change would need to be made in the upstream library. How can this change be made without modifying the upstream library?

Comment: I've attempted to modify the `INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property of the target, but that doesn't remove the warnings.
`get_target_property(gtest_include_dirs gtest INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
set_target_properties(gtest PROPERTIES INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES gtest_include_dirs)`

Answer (score 0):

[CMake's issue 21211](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21211) has a few interesting points, and provides this "fix":
Use

```
get_property(_foo_include_dirs TARGET foo PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
set_property(TARGET foo PROPERTY INTERFACE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_foo_include_dirs}")
```

to make the include directories of target `foo` appear as system includes in your project, even though they were not defined as `SYSTEM` includes in your dependency.